# Which WPF element was used for the Visual Studio code editor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

According to [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75322/which-language-was-used-to-create-visual-studio-2010),  Visual Studio was rewritten using WPF. I'm trying to figure out what Element is used for the code editor window (specifically C#, if there's a difference) but I can't figure out which element could have all of that functionality (obviously with a lot of extra work. But still...).

I want to know this is so that I can experiment writing my own little code editor. (Yes, I know a full-fledged editor is a very large project. I'm talking about a simple custom one.)

Comment: Probably highly custom.

Comment: @H.B. Of course. (That's what I meant by `obviously with a lot of extra work`.)  But what would be the base XAML element?

Comment: Have you tried snooping Visual Studio?

Comment: @Bijington Sounds promising. How would I do that?

Comment: @ispiro download snoop from https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ and then point it at visual studio it is a fantastic tool for diagnosing issues in WPF

Comment: @Bijington Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a quick Snoop I can see that the base element is:
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView` so it is very much a custom job.

I don't know what access you can get to the libraries but there is documentation around the namespace here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.aspx

Comment: Not directly related, but do you think MS would eventually open-souce all these code-bases?

Comment: @heltonbiker personally I would say no because I believe MS still see they have a lot of value in the tool but then again I didn't expect them to open-source the .NET Framework...